# Count Rank in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame like this. Invoices are transformed into a table where each row has a single product for each customer. This table consists of millions of rows -

| customer | invoice | products |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | INVC001 | xx |
| a | INVC001 | yy |
| a | INVC002 | zz |
| a | INVC003 | aa |
| b | INVC004 | xx |
| b | INVC004 | aa |
| b | INVC004 | bb |
| b | INVC005 | cc |

Now I want to create a column where I want to rank each customers invoices. The table I want

| customer | invoice | products | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | INVC001 | xx | 1 |
| a | INVC001 | yy | 1 |
| a | INVC002 | zz | 2 |
| a | INVC003 | aa | 3 |
| b | INVC004 | xx | 1 |
| b | INVC004 | aa | 1 |
| b | INVC004 | bb | 1 |
| b | INVC005 | cc | 2 |

I tried to use cumcount, with grouping customer and invoices with this code `df.groupby(['customer','invoice'])['invoice'].cumcount()+1`, also tried `nggroup()` but could not generate my expected output.

Is there any numpy/pandas way to create a table like this? Or, is there any optimized way to do this.

Comment: There's `rank()` method for dataframes and series. You should probably use it instead:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('customer')['invoice'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]) + 1
```

For me `rank` failed:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('customer')['invoice'].rank(method='dense')
```

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Solution should be like mentioned @pavel:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('customer')['invoice'].rank(method='dense', numeric_only=False)
```

Comment: Set `numeric_only` flag  to False for `rank()` to work with non-numeric objects